# How to user whereIn with array having null value(conditionally)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravell and sql , I will have two scenarios both depends on user input
and this column may have null value so final array will looks like

DB Data

```
col1   col2
abc    xyz
abc2   xyz2
null   null
abc3   xyz3
```

Scenario1 :

```
col1 = ["abc","abc2","abc3"];
col2 = ["xyz","xyz2","xyz3"];
```

Scenario1 :

```
col1 = ["abc","abc2","abc"];
col2 = ["xyz","xyz2",null];
```

MY query is based on user input , for example col1 can be empty i.e null and col2 i.e null

I am using this query :

```
$query->whereIn( $field, $col1);
$query->whereIn( $field2, $col2);
```

for scenario 1 :
every thing works fine

```
col1   col2
abc    xyz
abc2   xyz2
abc3   xyz3
```

for scenario 1 :
not working with null

```
col1   col2
```

empty

and with this query

```
$query->whereIn( $field, $col1);
$query->orWhereNull($field)
$query->whereIn( $field2, $col2);
$query->orWhereNull($field2)
```

no results

can any one guide me in the right direction how can i have the results with null also
and FYI its  AND query i.e filter col1 && col2

Comment: soo confusing just bee specific

Comment: @JEJ query to obtain results when input can have null values in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can test it right now, but you need to separate your statement.
Something like :

```php
$query->whereHas($field, function ($query) use ($field, $col1) {
    if (in_array(null, $col1)) {
        $query->whereNull($field)->orWhereIn($field, $col1);
    } else {
        $query->whereIn($field, $col1);
    }
});
$query->whereHas($field2, function ($query) use ($field2, $col2) {
    if (in_array(null, $col2)) {
        $query->whereNull($field2)->orWhereIn($field2, $col2);
    } else {
        $query->whereIn($field2, $col2);
    }
});
```